# How to get Document ID from firestore database collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a mobile app with React Native & Firebase and currently trying to get a document data using this method as an example

```
const docRef = db.collection('vehicle').doc('2l3bcSGs2vZBIc3RODwp').get()
```

as you can see, I explicitly use the ID **"2l3bcSGs2vZBIc3RODwp"** as the parameter in docRef method, while I am trying to get the ID without using it explicitly.

EDIT : FIREBASE CONFIG

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth,initializeAuth ,getReactNativePersistence} from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

//config key


 const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
initializeAuth(app, {
    persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage)
  });
  
 const database = getFirestore(app);
 const auth = getAuth(app);

export{auth,database};
```

How can I modify the method?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the get() method on the collection reference and then iterating over the documents in the result. Each document in the result has an automatically generated unique identifier called the document ID.

```
import { db } from './your-firebase-config';
const vehicleCollection = db.collection('vehicle');
vehicleCollection.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
   querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
     console.log('Document ID:', doc.id);
     console.log('Document Data:', doc.data());
   });
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error getting documents:', error);
});
```

Comment: It seems a good solution, but I received an error " Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'Firestore'.ts ", while I already have initialized the getFirestore config. Any idea why?